# extract field based on the last character

Tags: extract, cut

I want extract part of the field based on the last character K. Every field ends with K and the one that I want to extract has only 4 characters.

I have something like this

```
fromdata.set.days/john001.00.K 

fromdata.set.days/bian001.00.K

fromdata.set.days/aluo001.00.K

fromdata.set.days/mark001.00.K
```

I want to extract from the above the following 4 character names

```
john

bian

aluo

mark
```

Comment: Need a little more context - are you trying to do this in a shell script, or in C/C++ or something else?

Comment: I want to solve with  a combination of "cut" and/or "awk" and/or "grep"  and finally  assign to a variable. I want to use this variable to search and match and find a value that corresponds to it. For each name there is a corresponding coordinate in another file.

Comment: So, something like `echo $filename | sed -e 's;.*/;;' -e 's/[0-9].*//'` might work for you. The first expression strips everyting up to the '/', the second finds the first digit and strips from there to the end.

Comment: It does work for 99% of the the time but fails when the character name contains numerals. for instance if the file name is say: .../bal1.00.K, the result is "bal". The correct result would have been "bal1".

Comment: In that case, maybe `echo $filename | awk -F/ '{print substr($2,1,4)}'` - assuming that there will only ever be one '/'...

Comment: Thank you again. Apparently there are 7 of these "/" and one of this "//".

Comment: cat $filename |  cut -d'/'  -f10 | awk  '{print substr($1,1,4)}' , this seems to work.

Comment: To assign a variable I hope this should work
myavr= "$(cat $i |  cut -d'/'  -f10 |  awk  '{print toupper(substr($1,1,4))}')" or

myavr= `(cat $i |  cut -d'/'  -f10 |  awk  '{print toupper(substr($1,1,4))}')' 


-------------                                                                                                                                         for t in ${myvar[@]}
do
    echo $t
done                                                                or does it ?

Answer (score 1):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk -F/ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(substr($i,length($i))=="K") print substr($i,1,4) }' file
```

It delimits the file on `/` and then look for last character on each column. If it ends with `K` then it prints the first 4 characters of that column.

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
fromdata.set.days/john001.00.K
fromdata.set.days/bian001.00.K
fromdata.set.days/aluo001.00.K
fromdata.set.days/mark001.00.K

$ awk -F/ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(substr($i,length($i))=="K") print substr($i,1,4) }' file
john
bian
aluo
mark
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you state in your comment above that you want to assign this list to a variable and iterate over the names in a loop, there is no need to use `awk` or another external tool - just use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ cat foo.txt
fromdata.set.days/john001.00.K
fromdata.set.days/bian001.00.K
fromdata.set.days/aluo001.00.K
fromdata.set.days/mark001.00.K

$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
        name=${line#*/}
        name=${name:0:4}
        echo "${name}"
done < foo.txt
```

Example run:

```
$ ./test.sh
john
bian
aluo
mark
```